# CAN we do something like <% alert("TEMP") %> in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have sent a variable in node.js from `res.render()` function and I have to use that variable for my script in EJS templating for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Node.js:

```
res.render('index', {TEMP: 'xyz'});
```

In the HTML:

```
<p>This is a HTML demo</p>
<div>
   I'm the TEMP variable: <%= TEMP %> <!-- this is going to output xyz -->
   <script>
       var getTemp = <%= TEMP  %>;
       console.log(getTemp);
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: can i use this var TEMP as <script>console.log(TEMP)</script>. Is it possible in node..???

Comment: You can do that with `<% console.log(TEMP) %>`